# Determinant of a 3x3 matrix vanishes?

Tags: matrices, determinant, jacobian

I have to find the eigenvalues of the following Jacobian matrix. I usually just proceed by computing the determinant $det(J - \lambda \mathbb I)$, however in this case I can't do this as my formula vanishes due to the 1st column of zeros.

In this case, what can I do?

$$
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & b\\
0  & c  & 0 \\
0 & d & e 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Are you saying that you found that $\det(J-\lambda I)=0$?

Comment: 1. When you add $\lambda\mathbb I$ the problem with the column of zeros goes away.  2. Permute the last 2 rows and the last 2 columns, and the answer should stand out.

Comment: @RedPen Then you miscomputed the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\det \begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & a & b  \\ 0 & c-\lambda & 0   \\ 0 & d & e-\lambda \\
\end{bmatrix} = -\lambda(c -\lambda)(e-\lambda).
\end{eqnarray*}